# If a Jedi knight were frozen in carbonite, would they be able to use their Force powers?

Tags: star-wars

This question arose when [some](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/2922/laura) of my [coworkers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/2459/aarthi-devanathan) threatened to freeze me in carbonite and use me as a coffee table. (I did nothing to deserve this threat. Nothing!) I posited that I would just knock anything they tried to put on coffee-table-me onto the ground with my mind.

Is this something a Jedi would be able to do if frozen in carbonite? **Is the frozen person conscious inside the carbonite, or is their mind frozen too?** Would a frozen Jedi be able to use the Force to manipulate objects outside of the carbonite block (and therefore potentially be able to escape)?

Comment: Also there is A Clone Wars episode where Jedi are put in carbonite, so they are not able to be sensed by sensors. I forget which one though. I think it is in season 4.

Comment: Is this restricted to just Jedis, or Sith as well?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

In the [Legacy of the Force](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Legacy_of_the_Force) novels in the EU several Jedi are frozen in carbonite as they appear to be acting irrationally and violating GA Laws.  These Jedi are unable to influence the world.  As @Keen notes even Jedi go into hibernation when frozen in carbonite.

Comment: Accepted for referencing source material

Answer (score 42):

Unfortunately, no, you would not be able to manifest your force powers while frozen in carbonite:

> **C-3PO**: Oh. They've encased him in Carbonite. He should be quite well protected. If he survived the freezing process, that is.
>
> **Darth Vader**: Well, Calrissian, did he survive?
>
> **Lando**: Yes, he's alive, and in perfect hibernation.
>
> **Darth Vader**: He's all yours, bounty hunter.

Hibernation means that the individual is unconscious.

[Here](http://boards.theforce.net/literature/b10003/30073805/r30074661/) is a related conversation.

Comment: I would almost say it's fortunate, not unfortunate.  Can you imagine what it would have been like for Han (or anyone else) to be frozen in a space like that, unable to move, and your mind still be active?  That way lies madness.

Comment: Well, it is unfortunate for the coffee table who wants to keep her surface clear of her coworkers' belongings....

Comment: So if someone were conscious in carbonite, you could make a Jedi coffee table that automatically cleans itself of stains and spills and tidies itself up whenever items on it are disorganized.

Comment: This is correct and was even covered in the Star Wars: Clone Wars animated series

Answer (score 25):

No, as when you're [frozen in carbonite](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Carbon_freezing), you go into [hibernation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Suspended_animation).  As such, you're unconscious while in the carbonite, and that means no force powers.  Although you might have some visions of the future, as Jedi are known to have.

Answer (score 16):

In doing a little unrelated carbonite freezing research, I came across mention of [Roni von Wasaki](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Roni_von_Wasaki), and was surprised to see mention of his use of the Jedi Mind Trick *while encased in carbonite* (emphasis mine):

> Confiscating Wasaki's lightsaber and shoto, Drobo froze him in carbonite and stored him in the hold of his ship, the Starkiller.
>
> **Still attempting to resist capture in hibernation, Wasaki mentally reached out to Drobo, convincing the captain to free him and return his weapons**. However, XT-8 learned of that and killed Drobo, as he had become a liability. In the process, XT-8 damaged the Starkiller's hyperdrive. The droid, unable to repair the ship, continued the trip on sublight drive, turning a thirty day jump into 20,000 years.
>
> **Wasaki persisted in his frozen state, continually trying to reach anyone passing within close proximity of the ship. Though the carbonite preserved him, the elongated journey slowly drove him insane, leaving him with twenty millennia of lonely thoughts and dreams**. His situation also left him permanently blind, leaving him with only the Force to rely on.

Note that this is from an [adventure for the Star Wars roleplaying game](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Disturbance_in_the_Force_(article)), making it potentially [C-canon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_canon) that yes, a Jedi could remain conscious while encased in carbonite, and influence the world (albeit perhaps not physical manipulation) from within the carbonite.  However, the carbonite freezing process used on Wasaki was that of almost 20,000 years *prior* to the experimental technique used by Darth Vader on Han Solo, so it could be conceivable that some difference in the process resulted in later applications of carbon freezing inducing a true hibernation state.

Answer (score 1):

If a Jedi could use his powers in carbonite, would Darth Vader have wanted Luke to travel in that method? (remember, freezing Han was only a test; the bounty hunters strongly prefered to just take him alive, rather than risk killing him and losing their reward.)

Comment: Before Luke finally encounters Vader on Bespin, Vader refers to Luke as, "just a boy" and has no idea about Luke's training with Yoda. It can be interpreted as though he does not think much of Luke's abilities at this point.